# Python: Is there a way to force a parent function to return?

Tags: python, exception

In my program I have a function that handles `requests` calls, and either returns the processed call or raises an exception. This function is used by many other functions, however, the problem I'm running into is how to handle the exception that may possibly be raised. Currently it is set up like so (simplified):

```
def getFromAPI(url):
    # create variable headers
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 404:
        raise Exception("Error raised")
    else:
        #process data
        return data

def functionone():
    ...
    try:
        data = getFromAPI(url)
    except Exception as e:
        return handleException(e) 
        #handles problems, returns exception-formatted data

    ...
    # formatting data specific to functionone
    return formatted_data

def functiontwo():
    ...
    try:
        data = getFromAPI(url)
    except Exception as e:
        return handleException(e) 
        #handles problems, returns exception-formatted data

    ...
    # formatting data specific to functiontwo
    return formatted_data

def functionthree():
    ...
    #similar to functionone and functiontwo
```

While I don't think this is wrong, per se, since `getFromAPI` is used in so many functions, having to constantly repeat the try except statements feels wrong, as if it should be handled within the function `getFromAPI`. However, since the other `functionone` through `function_n` all return different things depending on whether an error was raised, I can't see a way to handle that from within `getFromAPI`, unless there is a way for `getFromAPI` to force it's parent function to return, without explicitly calling return in the parent function.

Failing that, is there a better implementation of what I'm trying to do, or am I doomed to keep repeating the try except statements?

Comment: let it fail loudly and catch it further up ... dont handle the problem in each function

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over functions further up.

Comment: By "further up" do mean the callers of `functionone`..`functionthree`? Or the direct callers of `getFromAPI`?

Comment: The callers of `functionone`..`functionthree`

Comment: Write a decorator for functions which call `getFromAPI` that catches and formats the exception and then don't try to catch the exception within functionone etc.

Answer (score 8):

Write a decorator like this

```
def catchAPIException(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except getFromAPIException as e:
            return handleException(e)
    return wrapper
```

Then your `functionone` etc just look like

```
@catchAPIException
def functionone():
    ...
    data = getFromAPI(url)
    ...
    # formatting data specific to functionone
    return formatted_data
```

But you want to raise a very specific **custom** Exception so that your decorator will **only** catch the relevant one. Or perhaps you should create a number of different exceptions which can be handled differently.

If different functions want to format the exception in a custom way, the decorator can be passed another function which is actually used to format it. I.e. make `handleException` a parameter to `catchAPIException`

```
def catchAPIException(exceptionHandler = handleException):
    def real_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except getFromAPIException as e:
                return exceptionHandler(e)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

then functions which are happy with the default exception handler are declared like this:

```
@catchAPIException
def function1():
    ...
```

Others with more specific needs can do this:

```
def customExceptionHandler(e):
    ...

@catchAPIException(customExceptionHandler)
def function2():
    ...
```

If you are unfamiliar with decorators, here is a [reasonable tutorial](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) and there are the Python docs as well though they don't have an explicit section on them.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this isn't exactly an answer to the asked question, but it's one of the questions I came across trying to find a similar solution

Solution - forcing parent to return if child function returns None

```
class ParentShouldReturnException(Exception):
    pass


def return_custom_value_if_child_returns_none(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('inside return_custom_value_if_child_returns_none')
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ParentShouldReturnException:
            print('ParentShouldReturnException was raised, returning')
            return 'forced return'
        return result
    return wrapper


def raise_parent_should_return_exception_if_result_is_none(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('inside raise_parent_should_return_exception_if_result_is_none')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result is None:
            print('raising ParentShouldReturnException')
            raise ParentShouldReturnException
        return result
    return wrapper


@raise_parent_should_return_exception_if_result_is_none
def child_func(a):
    return a


@return_custom_value_if_child_returns_none
def parent_func(input_arg1):
    return child_func(input_arg1)

print('example 1 - normal')
result = parent_func('nothing interesting')
print(f'{result=}')
print()
print('example 2 - return from child')
result = parent_func(None)
print(f'{result=}')
```

this outputs

```
example 1 - normal
inside return_custom_value_if_child_returns_none
inside raise_parent_should_return_exception_if_result_is_none
result='nothing interesting'

example 2 - return from child
inside return_custom_value_if_child_returns_none
inside raise_parent_should_return_exception_if_result_is_none
raising ParentShouldReturnException
ParentShouldReturnException was raised, returning
result='forced return'
```